# Python pandas replace pattern

Tags: python, pandas

this is my first question, so first of all, I wanted to say that I appreciate the information from stack overflow community and have found many solutions to my problems since today. Please excuse my poor skills since I just started learning Python and am not a professional programmer by any means.

Problem is as followed, I imported a dataframe from an excel file with several hundred rows and columns with multiline strings, which I need now to clean up.

**Inputfile**

| From        | To |
| ----------- | -- |
| /7
/8
123.456.7
A-300A/A
TEXTA1
/8
/7
A123.456.7
AB-6005B/7A
/7 | 123.456.7
B-300B/8
TEXTB2
/8
/7
B123.456.7
B-6005B/7
/7
 |
[This is what the Input looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxbOA.png)

Normally the pattern is like `(.*)\.\d{3}\.\d` (A123.345.6 or just 123.345.6) or `[A-Z]{1,2}-\d*[A-Z]{0,2}\/(.{0,2})` (A-300A/A or AB-6005B/7A). I managed to organize my data (got rid of TEXTA1, white-spaces, etc.) in a column ['To'] to a certain point until i reached this:
[multiline string cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/boQH4.png)

I used `df['To']=df['To'].str.replace('\/\d$', "",regex=True, flags=re.MULTILINE)` and without the MULTILINE flag, but it either replaces only the last `\7` or every `\` with a digit. But the result should be as following

**Outputfile**
| From        | To |
| ----------- | -- |
| 123.456.7
A-300A/A
A123.456.7
A-6005B/7 | 123.456.7
B-300B/B
B123.456.7
B-6005B/7
 |
[This is what the Output should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1vGJf.png)

Is there a way to simply delete everything that **doesn't** match both the pattern mentioned above instead of replacing each wrong entry?
It feels to complicated to sort every mistake instead of just choosing the correct lines.

Comment: I would be best if you posted some sample data to be cleaned and expected output from this sample data.  This way we can verify that we are providing you a working good solution.

Comment: `(.*)\.\d*3\.\d` does not math the pattern `A123.345.6` . . . Do you mean `(.*)\.\d*3.\d\.\d`

Comment: Are you looking for `df['To'].str.replace('(.*)\.\d*3.\d\.\d|[A-Z]*-\d*\/(.*)', '', regex=True)`?

Comment: I corrected the pattern and tried to include table of what In and Output look like, but I did something wrong so pictures are also attached.